# Underline specific words of a string in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I've got a string being sent to a class that is split by \n for format. I was wondering if it was possible to underline specific words of the string so it looks better?

Currently this is what is being passed

```
"Name : Jackson 
\nLabel: Movie
\nDirector: 
\nGenre: Action
\nActors: Will, Jack, Carrie
\nMetascore: 90/100
\nRevenue: 87.5M
\nRuntime: 100 min
\nRating: 9/10"
```

And I would like for the word after the \n until the ":" to be underlined but all I've seen are making an entire string underlined.

Heres how I'm currently parsing the string.

```
 const newText = text.split('\n').map(str => <p>{str}</p>);
```

My guess would be to have str split again by : inside the .map and using
`<Text style={styles.bold}> </Text>` to set it?

Comment: which words do you wanna underline ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split each line of your text by `:`, like below:

```js
const string = `
Name: Jackson 
Label: Movie
Director: 
Genre: Action
Actors: Will, Jack, Carrie
Metascore: 90/100
Revenue: 87.5M
Runtime: 100 min
Rating: 9/10
`;

function MyList() {
  const strings = string.split('\n').map((str) => {
    const [label, value] = str.split(':');
    return (
      <div>
        <u>{label}</u>:<p>{value}</p>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return strings;
}
```

`<u>` stands for underline in html.

You can also add a `className` attribute to the tag surrounding the `label` part and use `text-decoration: underline;`

Answer (score 0):

Try `text.split(/[\n:]/)`.
After that - put each uneven element into a tag.
Of course it will work only if there are no other colons or new lines in text.

```js
const str = "Name : Jackson\nLabel: Movie\nDirector: \nGenre: Action\nActors: Will, Jack, Carrie\nMetascore: 90/100\nRevenue: 87.5M\nRuntime: 100 min\nRating: 9/10"

console.log(str.split(/\s?[\n:]\s?/).map((s, i) => i % 2 === 0 ? ('<u>' + s + '</u>:') : (' ' + s + '\n')).join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string inside the map function, wrap it in span tags and use `text-decoration: underline;` for css.